Add a file to kivymd Android
I have some python code in which there is an import of this file, when I use it without this file in the directory, then my application does not run, I would like to know if it is possible to compile kivymd for android so that this file is inside the apk, I have provided my download code for this file, preferably that-it would have remained the same, but I'm ready to change the code to the right one if it helps. When running the program on a computer via python3 mobile.py the code also crashes without the necessary file in the directory, but if the file is there, then everything works.
with open("services.json", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as file:
    services = json.load(file)["services"]

I tried to add a file to the directory of the installed android application, but it still wouldn't run. The kivy logo appeared, then disappeared, and the app was immediately turned off.

Have you tried the source.include_patterns or source.include_exts in your spec file?
